# Kotlin + Mockito + Spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockito, serenity-bdd

I am studying Kotlin with Spring Boot, and I am trying to use Serenity just for report.
But I have some problem with Mockito because I cannot mock the last part of my code.

That's my case:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var personUseCase : PersonUseCase


    @GetMapping("/all")
    fun findAllPeople(): DataModelResponse<List<PersonDataModelResponse>> {
        return DataModelResponse(
                PersonDataModelResponseMapper.transform(personUseCase.findAll()))
    }

}
```

```java
@Component
class PersonUseCase {

    fun findAll(): List<PersonEntity> {
        val personImpl : Person = PersonImplementation()
        return personImpl.findAll()
    }
}
```

```java
class PersonImplementation : Person {

    private val personDaoResponse :  PersonDaoResponse = PersonDaoResponse()

    override fun findAll(): List<PersonEntity> {

        val listPeopleDao = personDaoResponse.findAll()

        return PersonDaoMapper.transform(listPeopleDao)
    }

}
```

```java
internal class PersonDaoResponse (
        val identification: Long = 0,
        val personName: String = "") {

    fun findAll(): List<PersonDaoResponse> {
        return listOf(PersonDaoResponse(1, "José"))
    }
}
```

And I am trying to mock my Dao in an integration test:

```java
@RunWith(SerenityRunner::class)
@WithTag("Integration")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest
class PersonControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var personController : PersonController

    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var personImplementation : PersonImplementation

    @SpyBean
    private lateinit var personUseCase : PersonUseCase

    @Spy
    private val personDaoResponse = PersonDaoResponse()

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var webApplicationContext: WebApplicationContext

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Rule @JvmField
    var springMethodIntegration = SpringIntegrationMethodRule()

    @Before
    fun init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        reset(personDaoResponse)

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build()
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(personController).setMessageConverters(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()).build()
    }

    @Test
    fun `integration success`() {
        doReturn(listOf(PersonDaoResponse(999L, "Zé")))
                .`when`(this.personDaoResponse).findAll()
        val result = this.personController.findAllPeople()
        assertNotNull(result)
        assertEquals(999L, result.data[0].personId)
        assertEquals("Zé", result.data[0].name)
    }

}
```

I know this mock is working if I do something I try call the mock method:
assertEquals(999L, this.personDaoResponse.findAll()[0].identification)

How can I Mock this Dao in an integration test like this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for the Mockito problem because I've been off Mockito for way to long.

If Mockito is not a must, I recommend using MockK (https://github.com/mockk/mockk) from my Spring Boot + Kotlin experience. If you need injectable mocked Beans as well, you can add SpringMockK (https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk) as well.

As your "PersonDaoResponse" is constructed within the PersonImplementation class, you could use something like this with MockK:

```
every { anyConstructed<PersonDaoResponse>().findAll() } returns listOf(PersonDaoResponse(999L, "Zé"))
```